# Efficiently computing $\sum_{\sqrt{N} \lt p \in primes \leq N} \lfloor \frac{N}{p} \rfloor$

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, computational-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm interested in computing $f(N) = \sum_{\sqrt{N} \lt p \in primes \leq N} \lfloor \frac{N}{p} \rfloor$

$N$ is large enough that primes up to $\sqrt{N}$ are available, but not much beyond and certainly not to $N$.

There's some flexibility about the range, in that a $g(N)$ summing over $1 \lt p \in primes \leq N$ would be just as useful and give $f(N) = g(N)-g(\sqrt{N})$.

The most/only obvious improvement I can think of - compared with the completely infeasible prime search up to $N$ - is using the prime counting function $\pi(n)$: there are $\pi(N)-\pi(\frac{N}{2})$ primes contributing 1 to the sum, $\pi(\frac{N}{2})-\pi(\frac{N}{3})$ primes contributing 2 to the sum and so on.  However while there seem to be practical implementations for computing $\pi(N)$ using only primes to $\sqrt{N}$ (e.g sympy's [`primepi`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.generate.primepi)), in practice the computational complexity means $\pi({N})$ still seems to be out of practical reach.

Is there any trick which will help compute this sum?

Comment: Perhaps you should mention the source of the problem. Did it just come to your mind, or did you see it from some online programming contest or anything like that? In the latter case it would be better to link the source, so that people know it's not an ongoing contest.

Comment: Besides, you could also mention the value of $N$ that you are interested in. Usually it is feasible for $N \sim 10^{12}$.

Comment: @WhatsUp: Yes it's from a problem posed online but 1. I am wary of linking to it and spoiling others' fun if there ends up being a useful solution here discoverable by search.  2. In any case I am pretty sure an approach using the calculation in this question is the wrong one, but I was intrigued enough by it in it's own right to wonder whether its feasible.

Comment: @WhatsUp: Mentioning a number can be a bit of a distraction IMHO; tends to lead to discussion of implementation tricks rather than the mathematics.  GP/PARI does indeed seem to be able to do `primepi(10^10)` in a few seconds but $10^{11}$ took quite a bit longer.  But I'm more interested in whether there's something about this sum which makes it easier via a different line of attack than a $\pi{(n)}$ based one.

Comment: The number does matter, as you are doing an online programming challenge. If your $N$ is something larger than $10^{14}$ then probably you should find another approach. If it is around $10^{12}$ then this method may be the intended one - you just have to figure out how to calculate $\pi(x)$ more efficiently.

Comment: @WhatsUp: Fresh development: found a comment at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41862143/24283 suggesting that PARI's primecount's performance becomes suboptimal for larger numbers.  Surprising to me as for most things it seems remarkably fast.  Hunting around for something better led to https://github.com/kimwalisch/primecount/blob/master/doc/libprimecount.md and claims (from a Julia wrapping of it) that it can do $10^{14}$ in half a second and $10^{19}$ in 5 minutes, which are more like what I'm interested in.  Clearly I need to recalibrate my PARI-based impressions of what's feasible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment thread under my question reveals, the fundamental issue here was that I just didn't understand how fast prime counting can be.  Kudos to [libprimecount](https://github.com/kimwalisch/primecount) which can do astonishing (to me) numbers like $10^{18}$ in a matter of seconds.

Using that, I was able to solve my problem easily.

Using the prime counting function $\pi(n)$, the sum in the question can be evaluated by

$\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{N}-1} k.(\pi( \lfloor {\frac{N}{k}} \rfloor ) - \pi( \lfloor \frac{N}{k+1} \rfloor ))$

or

$ - (\sqrt{N}-1).\pi( \lfloor \sqrt{N} \rfloor ) + \sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{N}-1} \pi({ \lfloor \frac{N}{k}} \rfloor ) $

And as a check, some python code, just using sympy's prime tools, nothing fancy.  `bfS` is the literal implementation of the question, and `S` and `T` implement the two forms above.

```
from sympy.ntheory.generate import primerange
from sympy.ntheory import primepi

def check(N):

    sqrtN=int(N**0.5)
    assert sqrtN**2<=N
    assert (sqrtN+1)**2>N

    # Bruteforce it
    bfS=sum(N//p for p in primerange(sqrtN+1,N+1))

    # Use primepi
    kpi={k:primepi(N//k) for k in range(1,sqrtN+1)}
    S=sum(k*(kpi[k]-kpi[k+1]) for k in range(1,sqrtN))
    assert S==bfS

    T=sum(kpi[k] for k in range(1,sqrtN)) - (sqrtN-1)*primepi(sqrtN)
    assert T==bfS

for e in range(1,7):
    check(10**e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the fastest way to compute this sum exactly is to note that
$$
\sum_{L<p\le N} \bigg\lfloor \frac Np \bigg\rfloor = \sum_{L<p\le N} \sum_{\substack{1\le k\le N \\ p\mid k}} 1 = \sum_{1\le k\le N} \sum_{\substack{L<p\le N \\ p\mid k}} 1.
$$
(I use the parameter $L$ because the OP's title, where $L=1$, doesn't match the question asked in the body, where $L=\sqrt N$.)

Sums of factorization-related functions over all intervals in a range can be accomplished using the sieve of Eratosthenes with a little extra bookkeeping: instead of simply "crossing out" multiples $k$ of each prime $p$, add $1$ to a counter for each such multiple $k$ when $p>L$. One only has to use the primes up to $\sqrt N$, and then all the other prime factors can be noted and counted (there is at most $1$ for any integer in that range).

It seems that just using the standard sieve of Eratosthenes to compute all the primes up to $N$, and then evaluating the sum $\sum_{L<p\le N} \big\lfloor \frac Np \big\rfloor$, isn't that much slower. Both of them will take (space $N$ and) time that is something like $N(\log N)^C$.

Comment: There are faster (sublinear) algorithms.